# AJAX/PHP ajax data/echo returning with a "?>"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im having a strange bug in one of my pages.  In a simple Login, im using AJAX to check if the username exists. This is the 4th time i replicate the code, and it had no problem, until now.

The code works like this-> on click the button it passes the data to the index.  The index call the dispatcher Controller to the Validation controler, the Validation checks the username and the password, and if its all ok, it returns a ok.

However, the return comes with a '?>' added in the beggining. like it escaped from a php.
That character is nowhere in the Dispacther, ValidationControler, index,so it was not added from there. I am returning the data with a simple echo,

The button javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("ready",function(){
$("#btn-enviar").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var pet = $("form").attr("action"); //pagina url  modificable?
var met = $("form").attr("method"); //post?
  $.ajax({
   url: "index.php?ctrl=validation&action=login",
  type: met,
  data: $("form").serialize(),
   beforeSend: function () {
                $("#resultado").html("Cargando...");    
    },
    success: function(data){    
     if(data=="ok")
     {
      $("#resultado").html(""+data);
     }
     else
     {
       $("#resultado").html(""+data);
     }
   },

  });
});
});
</script>
```

the validation Controller that gets called

```
 class validationController {

 public static function login(){
    $s=DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    if(!class_exists("promocion")){
        require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$s."model".$s."usuario.php");
    }

    $usuario=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $user = new usuario();
    $mensaje="Error usuario y/o contraseña";

    //se necesita el mensaje dado que es una funcion por AJAX 
    if($user->login($usuario, $password)){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $usuario;
        $mensaje="ok";
        echo $mensaje;
    }else{

        echo $mensaje;
    }
    sleep(1);
 }
}
```

the method login from the class usuario.php

```
function login($username,$password){
    if(!class_exists("userHelper")){
        require_once ("userHelper.php");
    }
    $helper=userHelper::getInstance();
    $user=$helper->login($username,$password);
    if($user==null){
        return false;
    }else{
        $this->correo=$user->correo;
        $this->id_usuario=$user->id_usuario;
        $this->password=$user->password;
        $this->privilegios=$user->privilegios;
        $this->username=$user->username;
        $this->telefono=$user->telefono;
        $this->direccion=$user->direccion;
        return true;
    }
}
```

and the userHelper.php  database connection for the login.

```
public function login($username,$password){
$pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE]=PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;  ///username, Pass, DB
$conn= new PDO($this->connection,$this->admin,$this->pass,$pdo_options);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `usuario` where username = :usuario and password= :password ");
$stmt->bindParam(':usuario',$username);
$stmt->bindParam(':password',$password);
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->fetchAll();
if ($result==FALSE){
        return null;
}else{
        $u=new usuario();
        foreach($result as $row){
            $u->setCorreo($row['correo']);
            $u->setId($row['id_usuario']);
            $u->setPassword($row['password']);

            $u->setUsuario($row['username']);
            $u->setDireccion($row['direccion']);
            $u->setTelefono($row['telefono']);
        return $u;
        }       
}
}
```

however, the return ends up like this

> "?>Error usuario y/o contraseña"

did a simple if data=="?>ok" to validate, but im still puzzled, why that ?> got added? its not a problem with the div, because "Cargando..." appears without the "?>"

Also, i did a echo var_dump($mensaje) and the return was "?>string(29)..."etc

Comment: Did you check this file `require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$s."model".$s."usuario.php");`? Maybe the output of `?>` occurs in there?

Comment: usuario.php only returns a boolean, or a object "usuario". So is not there

Comment: Would you mind posting the complete file? Also, what is happening in `new usuario();`? Maybe share these two files?

Comment: Ok. Stil...i wanted to keep it as small and in the focus as possible, since the other parts of the code works fine. they never return a string or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("ready",function(){
$("#btn-enviar").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var pet = $("form").attr("action"); //pagina url  modificable?
var met = $("form").attr("method"); //post?
  $.ajax({
   url: "index.php?ctrl=validation&action=login",
  type: met,
  data: $("form").serialize(),
   beforeSend: function () {
                $("#resultado").html("Cargando...");    
    },
    success: function(data){    
     if(data.message == 'ok')
     {
       output = data.message;
      $("#resultado").html(""+output);
     }
     else
     {
     output = data.message;
       $("#resultado").html(""+output);
     }
   },

  });
});
});
</script>
```

and in your controller

```html
<?php
public static function login(){
    $s=DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    if(!class_exists("promocion")){
        require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$s."model".$s."usuario.php");
    }

    $usuario=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $user = new usuario();
    $mensaje="Error usuario y/o contraseña";

    //se necesita el mensaje dado que es una funcion por AJAX 
    if($user->login($usuario, $password)){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $usuario;
        $mensaje="ok";
        $output = json_encode(array('message' => $mensaje));
            die($output);
    }else{

        $output = json_encode(array('message' => $mensaje));
            die($output);
    }
    sleep(1);
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: Does not work. It seems like it's stuck in the beforeSend loop. , "cargando..." is always in the div, and the session_start() never happens (in the "flawed" code, if you realodad, the session still started, and it redirected to the admin page.)  Maybe its something of the JSON. Json its kinda out of my zone of comfort (never really used it) so im not experienced enough to fiddle with it

Comment: Why don't you return `ok` when you call this function `$user->login($usuario, $password)`. You can actuall start session in the `$user->login($usuario, $password)` function

Comment: mostly for "clean software" guidelines.  sessions not in the Model, and similar stuff.  Anyways, thats not really relevant for the problem i think...